# Everything in view controller is being pushed up to the top

Tags: ios, swift, view, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a scroll view with 6 view controllers in it (side by side). The 4th view controller is putting all the things in it to the very top for some reason though. Please see the images below for example.

Here's what's happening:
[image: Happening]

Here's What it should do:
[image: Expected Behaviour]

I tried deleting all the constraints in storyboard and putting them back, but it didn't change. Here's the code I used to put the view controllers in the scroll view (I used PureLayout):

```
self.addChildViewController(vc1)
self.scrollView.addSubview(vc1.view)
vc1.view.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets(UIEdgeInsetsZero, excludingEdge: ALEdge.Right)
vc1.view.autoMatchDimension(ALDimension.Width, toDimension: ALDimension.Width, ofView: self.scrollView)
vc1.view.autoMatchDimension(ALDimension.Height, toDimension: ALDimension.Height, ofView: self.scrollView)

self.addChildViewController(vc2)
self.scrollView.addSubview(vc2.view)
vc2.view.autoPinEdge(ALEdge.Left, toEdge: ALEdge.Right, ofView: vc1.view)
vc2.view.autoMatchDimension(ALDimension.Width, toDimension: ALDimension.Width, ofView: self.scrollView)
vc2.view.autoMatchDimension(ALDimension.Height, toDimension: ALDimension.Height, ofView: self.scrollView)

self.addChildViewController(vc3)
self.scrollView.addSubview(vc3.view)
vc3.view.autoPinEdge(ALEdge.Left, toEdge: ALEdge.Right, ofView: vc2.view)
vc3.view.autoMatchDimension(ALDimension.Width, toDimension: ALDimension.Width, ofView: self.scrollView)
vc3.view.autoMatchDimension(ALDimension.Height, toDimension: ALDimension.Height, ofView: self.scrollView)

self.addChildViewController(vc4)
self.scrollView.addSubview(vc4.view)
vc4.view.autoPinEdge(ALEdge.Left, toEdge: ALEdge.Right, ofView: vc3.view)
vc4.view.autoMatchDimension(ALDimension.Width, toDimension: ALDimension.Width, ofView: self.scrollView)
vc4.view.autoMatchDimension(ALDimension.Height, toDimension: ALDimension.Height, ofView: self.scrollView)

self.addChildViewController(vc5)
self.scrollView.addSubview(vc5.view)
vc5.view.autoPinEdge(ALEdge.Left, toEdge: ALEdge.Right, ofView: vc4.view)
vc5.view.autoMatchDimension(ALDimension.Width, toDimension: ALDimension.Width, ofView: self.scrollView)
vc5.view.autoMatchDimension(ALDimension.Height, toDimension: ALDimension.Height, ofView: self.scrollView)

self.addChildViewController(vc6)
self.scrollView.addSubview(vc6.view)
vc6.view.autoPinEdge(ALEdge.Left, toEdge: ALEdge.Right, ofView: vc5.view)
vc6.view.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets(UIEdgeInsetsZero, excludingEdge: ALEdge.Left)
vc6.view.autoMatchDimension(ALDimension.Width, toDimension: ALDimension.Width, ofView: self.scrollView)
vc6.view.autoMatchDimension(ALDimension.Height, toDimension: ALDimension.Height, ofView: self.scrollView)
```

Here's the constraints for the "B" button for example:
[image: Constraints]

The view controller in storyboard:
[image: view controller]

The constraints for the imageview:
[image: constraints]

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted that's useful for solving your problem. The problem has to be in the constraints you set in the storyboard.

Comment: Updated. New image at bottom that shows constraints for button

Comment: Actually, looking at your images again, it looks like the y-position of vc4's view is wrong (so only the bottom of the view is on screen). I don't see how you're setting the y-position of the views within your scroll view.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! I only applied it to vc4 and it still worked for all of them for some reason.